# GWT Disclosure Panel with Bootstrap Button wrong layout

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3, gwtbootstrap3

I use a gwt disclosure panel with 2 gwtbootstrap3 (based on bootstrap 3.3.6) buttons inside. When I open the disclosure panel (in chrome browser) the layout of the buttons is broken (see image). 
[image: wrong button layout]

Then, when I hover the mouse over the buttons the layout gets magically fixed:

[image: correct layout after hovering]

As you can see the border around the buttons is drawn wrongly when the disclosure panel opens. After hovering the mouse over the button the buttons border is drawn correctly.
The button size is set to XS (extra small) and there are two css stylings:
margin-left = .5em;
float: right;
The rest is default bootstrap styling.

Anyone experiencing this behaviour with buttons relayouting when the mouse hovers over them?

Answer (score 1):

well this is not really a solution but a  workaround. Instead of using Disclosure Panel you can "emulate" the behaviour using Collapse . But of course you have todo alot yourself. And it does not look exactly like a disclosure panel ... but hey it renders the contents in a correct way.

Best regards
Hannes